# GooglePalm(). NotImplementedError: Need to determine which default deprecation schedule to use. within ?? minor releases

Tags: nlp, langchain, large-language-model, palm-pre

this code was working fine before, and now it raise this error when calling GooglePalm with langchain.
The error:

----> 8 llm = GooglePalm().
NotImplementedError: Need to determine which default deprecation schedule to use. within ?? minor releases.

My code:

```
import google.generativeai as palm
from langchain.embeddings import GooglePalmEmbeddings
from langchain.llms import GooglePalm
palm.configure(api_key=GOOGLE_API_KEY)
llm = GooglePalm()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by upgradown langchain version:

```
!pip uninstall langchain
!pip install langchain==0.0.339
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use a lower version of Langchain

```
langchain==0.0.284
langchain==0.0.339
```

and used code like

```
api_key = ''
llm = GooglePalm(google_api_key=api_key, temperature=0.2)
```